# Drupal Bootstrap Scroll Conflict with Readmore Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7

When I call a window resize and click the readmore link that is provided I get this message Additionally, the close link appears to get appear stuck when the characters are at a "in the goldie locks" line height area:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.js?n4eadf:121
(anonymous function) bootstrap.js?n4eadf:121
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:5095
elemData.handle jquery.js:4766
```

This is my actual function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(window).resize(function($){     
            jQuery('.subcontainer').readmore({
            speed: 75,
            maxHeight: 129
            });  
    });
});
```

Here is the reference error:

```
 $scrollableElement.once('bootstrap-anchors', function () {
    $scrollableElement.on('click.bootstrap-anchors', 'a[href*="#"]:not([data-toggle],    [data-target])', function(e) {
      this.scrollTo(e);
    });
  });
```

And Finally my called js:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.10/jquery.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/misc/drupal.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery.ui || document.write("<script src='/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/ui/ui/jquery-ui.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/misc/1.9/jquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.2.1"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/misc/1.9/overlay-parent.js?v=1.0"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/modules/contextual/contextual.js?v=1.0"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/ui/external/jquery.cookie.js?v=67fb34f6a866c40d0570"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/modules/gss/scripts/autocomplete.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/modules/toolbar/toolbar.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/affix.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/alert.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/button.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/carousel.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/collapse.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/modal.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/popover.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/tab.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/readmore.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script src="http://tsunami.crabdance.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/bootstrap/js/transition.js?n4eadf"></script>
<script>jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"bootstrap_tsunami","theme_token":"zeb-lBs7FuYRH5wwgGZbBZ5IpDYYfIqZkbQjisS0Auk","js":{"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap\/js\/bootstrap.js":1,"https:\/\/ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/1.10.2\/jquery.js":1,"0":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1,"https:\/\/ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jqueryui\/1.10.2\/jquery-ui.js":1,"1":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/jquery_update\/replace\/misc\/1.9\/jquery.ba-bbq.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/jquery_update\/replace\/misc\/1.9\/overlay-parent.js":1,"modules\/contextual\/contextual.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/jquery_update\/replace\/ui\/external\/jquery.cookie.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/gss\/scripts\/autocomplete.js":1,"modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/affix.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/alert.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/button.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/carousel.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/collapse.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/dropdown.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/modal.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/tooltip.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/popover.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/tab.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/readmore.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/js\/transition.js":1},"css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.css":1,"misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.theme.css":1,"misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.menu.css":1,"misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css":1,"modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.css":1,"modules\/contextual\/contextual.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/footer_sitemap\/footer_sitemap.css":1,"modules\/shortcut\/shortcut.css":1,"modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/bootstrap\/css\/bootstrap.min.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap_tsunami\/css\/style.css":1}},"gss":{"key":""},"overlay":{"paths":{"admin":"node\/*\/edit\nnode\/*\/delete\nnode\/*\/revisions\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/revert\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/delete\nnode\/add\nnode\/add\/*\noverlay\/dismiss-message\nuser\/*\/shortcuts\nadmin\nadmin\/*\nbatch\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/cancel\nuser\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/edit\/*","non_admin":"admin\/structure\/block\/demo\/*\nadmin\/reports\/status\/php"},"pathPrefixes":[],"ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"},"tableHeaderOffset":"Drupal.toolbar.height","bootstrap":{"anchorsFix":1,"anchorsSmoothScrolling":1,"popoverEnabled":1,"popoverOptions":{"animation":1,"html":0,"placement":"right","selector":"","trigger":"click hover","title":"","content":"","delay":0,"container":"body"},"tooltipEnabled":1,"tooltipOptions":{"animation":1,"html":0,"placement":"auto left","selector":"","trigger":"hover focus","delay":0,"container":"body"}}});</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Did you ever get any resolution on this?  I'm hitting the same error in a use of slides.js when scrolling from one slide to another...

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar error when integrating with flexslider plugin. Try to go to your Bootstrap Settings (yourdomain/admin/appearance/settings/yourtheme), unchecked the "Fix anchor positions". I turn that off and the error disappeared. See if it works for you.

**Javascript** (Tab) > **Anchors** > **Fix anchor positions**